# An unused declaration makes my program work Correctly?

Tags: java

So I wrote this code and I wrote " int number = input.nextInt(); " in it as an experiment. The program does exactly what I want it to, but I don't understand why this works. The variable is not used at all later on in the program, but if I remove it, the program stops working. Any ideas? My code below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/*
 * Name: Ki
 */
public class Countdown {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Create a Scanner object to accept the input from user
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Prompt the user to enter starting number, I just set it to 5 because 
        // that's what the program had as standard input.
        System.out.println("Enter the beginning number: ");

        // I don't know how this works. I had this here as an experiment, but
        // the program now doesn't work without it so I guess I'll leave it here.
        int number = input.nextInt();

        // sets max countdown value
        int i=5;

        // Make a loop that makes the program countdown until it reaches 2
        while(i>1) 
        {
            System.out.print(i + " ... \n");
            i--;
        }
        // Makes the program print 1 without dots and print stopped at the end 
        if (i==1) System.out.println(i);
        System.out.print("Stopped");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code ran the same on my machine with and without the `int number = input.nextInt();` line.  The real question is why are you asking for a beginning number when it's always going to countdown from 5 since that's what `i` is set to?

Comment: I'm supposed to get input from the user and countdown from that number, but yeah that's not what this is doing, crap. How would I go about getting the number from the user and counting down from there?

Comment: I answered down below, just replace all your `i` with `number` @Skry Blackfall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you create Scanner, but it doesn't do anything for the user yet.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

With `nextInt()` the program will wait for the user input.

```
int number = input.nextInt();
```

But after that you always use `i`, which is set to 5.

I guess you want to use the input number as the starting number. Change the later half to this:

```
    // You can remove: int i=5;

    while(number>1) 
    {
        System.out.print(number + " ... \n");
        number--;
    }
    // Makes the program print 1 without dots and print stopped at the end 
    if (number==1) System.out.println(number);
    System.out.print("Stopped");
```

Comment: Yeah. Really dumb mistake by me. I haven't slept in a couple days, thanks for this help man.

Answer (score 1):

```
 int number = input.nextInt();

    // sets max countdown value


    // Make a loop that makes the program countdown until it reaches 2
    while(number>1) 
    {
        System.out.print(number + " ... \n");
        number--;
    }
    // Makes the program print 1 without dots and print stopped at the end 
    if (number==1) System.out.println(number);
    System.out.print("Stopped");
```